# Side by side plots for PerformanceAnalytics in R

Tags: r, plot, xts, performanceanalytics

The following script plots 2 charts side by side:

```
require(xts)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
XTS1 <- structure(c(12, 7, 7, 22, 24, 30, 26, 23, 27, 30), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), .CLASS = structure("double", class = "CLASS"), formattable = structure(list(formatter = "formatC", format = structure(list(format = "f", digits = 2), .Names = c("format", "digits")), preproc = "percent_preproc", postproc = "percent_postproc"), .Names = c("formatter", "format", "preproc", "postproc")), index = structure(c(1413981900, 1413982800, 1413983700, 1413984600, 1413985500, 1413986400, 1413987300, 1413988200, 1413989100, 1413990000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(10L, 1L))
XTS2 <- XTS1 ^ 0.2
plot(XTS1)
plot(XTS2)
```

The following script fails to plot 2 charts side by side:

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
require(xts)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
XTS1 <- structure(c(12, 7, 7, 22, 24, 30, 26, 23, 27, 30), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), .CLASS = structure("double", class = "CLASS"), formattable = structure(list(formatter = "formatC", format = structure(list(format = "f", digits = 2), .Names = c("format", "digits")), preproc = "percent_preproc", postproc = "percent_postproc"), .Names = c("formatter", "format", "preproc", "postproc")), index = structure(c(1413981900, 1413982800, 1413983700, 1413984600, 1413985500, 1413986400, 1413987300, 1413988200, 1413989100, 1413990000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(10L, 1L))
XTS2 <- XTS1 ^ 0.2
charts.PerformanceSummary(XTS1)
charts.PerformanceSummary(XTS2)
```

Would anyone know how to get the latter script to plot 2 charts side by side?

I would like to avoid using another package if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `charts.PerformanceSummary` uses `layout` internally to set up its three plots. I think your best bet to get two side by side would be to save to plots as images and then put them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chart.PerformanceSummary` is really just a wrapper to several charts.

You could do this, and extend it to any number of symbols horizontally if you wish (more than 2 symbols if you wanted)[image]:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
# First row
chart.CumReturns(XTS1, ylab = "Cumulative Return", main = "give me a title")
chart.CumReturns(XTS2, ylab = "Cumulative Return", main = "give me a title2")
# second row
chart.BarVaR(XTS1)
chart.BarVaR(XTS2)

# third row
chart.Drawdown(XTS1, main = "DD title", ylab = "Drawdown", 
)
chart.Drawdown(XTS2, main = "", ylab = "Drawdown", 
)
```

You need to add the appropriate parameters to each plot for things like colour and titles (leaving that to you), but you have the flexibility of adding any charts from the wonderful `xts`, `quantmod`, `performanceAnalytics` packages (and others).